# Acceder a posición específica separada por _ en javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy recuperando la siguiente información de una API REST.

```
[{
    "date": "2019-06-12 18:00:00",
    "4_X_X_30_last": 9370,
    "7_X_X_7_last": 6724,
    "11_X_X_600_avg": 288,
    "21_X_X_650_last": 36.844795,
    "22_X_X_651_last": -2.289222,
    "23_X_X_652_last": 40.5,
    "24_X_X_659_last": 1.4,
    "2000_001EC095C448_X_33798_last": 6035,
    "2001_001EC095C448_X_33799_last": 9605,
    "2004_001EC0953976_X_34049_avg": 463,
    "2004_001EC0953976_X_34049_max": 467,
    "2004_001EC0953976_X_34049_min": 459
}]
```

Necesito recuperar el tercer valor que se encuentra detrás de las barras bajas (_) hasta el final, por ejemplo `4_X_X_30_last` tendria que ser `30_last` en el caso del último valor `2004_001EC0953976_X_34049_max`  sería `34049_max` y asi con todos menos con data.

Siempre tengo la misma estructura tres de (_) antes del ID

Otro de los problema es que tengo que seguir este formato para luego enviarlo a otro lado y no tengo claro como puedo meter eso en mi código

```
let formatearJSON = function(json) {
    console.log('Mostramos el valor del JSON:' + JSON.stringify(json));

    const array = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json)).map(function(element, index) {
        const date = element.date;
        const unixDate = (new Date(date).getTime() / 1000).toString().split('.')[0];
        delete element.date;
        for (var key in element) {
            element[key] = {
                type: isNaN(element[key]) ? 'String' : 'float',
                value: isNaN(element[key]) ? element[key] : parseFloat(element[key]),
                metadata: {
                    timestamp: {
                        type: 'Integer',
                        value: unixDate //Fecha ya convertida a formato UNIX
                    }
                }
            };
        }
        return element;
    });
    return array;
};
var json_format = formatearJSON(json);
for (let format of json_format) {
    selectedPerson = JSON.stringify(format);
}
return Jformat_fiware = selectedPerson;
```

He probado con slice pero no es lo que necesito ya que algunas veces es 3 dígitos y otras 6 como se ve. Tiene que ser al encontrar la tercera (_) y quedarse con eso hacia delante.

Un saludo.

EDIT01

Probando lo mencionado por pablo me da el error de hacerlo solo en el primer elemento, el resto sigue igual. Copio código.

```js
let pruebas = [{
            "date": "2019-06-12 18:00:00",
            "4_X_X_30_last": 9370,
            "7_X_X_7_last": 6724,
            "11_X_X_600_avg": 288,
            "21_X_X_650_last": 36.844795,
            "22_X_X_651_last": -2.289222,
            "23_X_X_652_last": 40.5,
            "24_X_X_659_last": 1.4,
            "2000_001EC095C448_X_33798_last": 6035,
            "2001_001EC095C448_X_33799_last": 9605,
            "2004_001EC0953976_X_34049_avg": 463,
            "2004_001EC0953976_X_34049_max": 467,
            "2004_001EC0953976_X_34049_min": 459
        }];

        //json es un string

        let regex2 = /"(?:[^_]+\_){3}(.+)" ?:/g;

        let formattedJsonpruebas = JSON.stringify(pruebas).replace(regex2, '"$1":'); //nos quedamos con el grupo 1 ($1)

        console.log('Mostramos el log: ' + formattedJsonpruebas);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puesto que un JSON es un string, podrías hacer la transformación antes de *parsearlo*:

```js
let json = JSON.stringify([{
    "date": "2019-06-12 18:00:00",
    "4_X_X_30_last": 9370,
    "7_X_X_7_last": 6724,
    "11_X_X_600_avg": 288,
    "21_X_X_650_last": 36.844795,
    "22_X_X_651_last": -2.289222,
    "23_X_X_652_last": 40.5,
    "24_X_X_659_last": 1.4,
    "2000_001EC095C448_X_33798_last": 6035,
    "2001_001EC095C448_X_33799_last": 9605,
    "2004_001EC0953976_X_34049_avg": 463,
    "2004_001EC0953976_X_34049_max": 467,
    "2004_001EC0953976_X_34049_min": 459
}], null, 2);



let regex= /"([a-zA-Z0-9]+_){3}/g;
console.log(json);

let formattedJson = json.replace(regex,'"');

console.log(JSON.parse(formattedJson));
```

La regexp explicada:

```
/"                    Busca comillas ...
 ([a-zA-Z0-9]+        seguidas de letras o números ...
              _)      con un _ al final ...
                {3}   tres veces.

                   /g;  de manera global
```

Comment: Gracias por la repuesta pablo tiene muy buena pinta pero da este error json.replace is not a function

Comment: En mi ejemplo json es el JSON (un string), en tu caso tendrías que hacer `JSON.stringify(json).replace(...)`

Comment: Hola solo lo hace con el primer elemento, el resto los deja igual que antes es muy raro

Comment: si pruebo el codigo de arriba sin las `` y con JSON.stringify(json).replace(...) pasa eso solo lo hace en el primer elemento.:S

Comment: Creo que lo he arreglado

Comment: Hola, pero no puedo ponerle a mi JSON el , null, 2); viene de una API como he puesto.

Comment: Solucionado!!!! muchas gracias :D

Comment: Ahora que estoy viendolo mas tranquilamente en Value me da NaN que puede ser?

Comment: Acabo de ver el problema y es que estamos eliminando data por completo.

Comment: Lo revisaré en un rato

Comment: Estoy pensando en recorrer antes el JSON guardar el valor de date hacer tu transformación y pasarle todo bien parseado a mi funcion

Comment: Estoy probando algo asi json.forEach(element => {
                var data = element.date;
                let regex = /"(?:[^_]+\_){3}(.+)"\s*:/g;
                let formattedJson = JSON.stringify(element, null, 2).replace(regex, '"$1":');
                //formattedJson = "date" + data;

                console.log('formattedJson new:' + formattedJson);

            });

Comment: Creo que lo he arreglado, simplificando la regex y el replace

Comment: El fallo estaba en que yo pensaba que `\w` era equivalente a `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, pero realmente es equivalente a `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Comment: Funciona perfectamente Pablo muchas gracia. Que locura de regex jaja